# Reformat interpolated strings AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, typescript

I'm still relatively new to JS and Angular and have a scenario that's probable a simple fix. In my angular template I display users posts as interpolated strings eg `<p> {{userpost}} </p>` 
Sometimes this string will contain a hyperlink, @ or #. What will be the most performant way of reformatting and link/# or predetermined sub-string within an interpolated string.

For example, if "userpost" contains a "www." string, wrap that in an `<a href>` tag

I'm guessing it could have something to do with ES6 template literals

Comment: It sounds like defining a directive is best for you though

Comment: Realized it will make more sense to transform the text into html when saving the users input and then rendering it back that way